# Making Data Tables Accessible for Screenreaders

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility, screen-readers

I need to revise a website to make it more accessible for users with screen readers. The biggest problem I'm running into is with data we have displayed in tables. Say the table is like this:

```
A | B | C
---------
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6
```

You would want it to be read as "A1,B2,C3,A4,B5,C6". Instead, the free reader I downloaded (Thunder) would read it as "A,B,C,1,2,3,4,5,6" which makes no sense to someone actually trying to understand the information presented.

Is there any markup that can make a screenreader read the table "properly"? What should a web developer do here?

Comment: Found this: http://www.freedomscientific.com/Training/CommonHTMLAttributes.asp

Comment: You should include the HTML in your question. And which version of HTML do you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see in a table is its header cells and only then the values associated with these header cells. If I was blind, I'd probably also need to first hear/read in Braille the content of these header cells too.
Still,  in a long table, I could forget easily which column related to what (was the Age column the 3rd or the 4th one?) so a mechanism that could tell / remind me - for any data cell - which header cell(s) are associated with it would be useful.
As a sighted user, I just have to look up or left. If I was blind, I'd rely on screen reader to do that: with your example, that'd allow me to hear "A,B,C,A1,B2,C3,A4,B5,C6" or "A,B,C,1,2,3,4,5,6" depending on my preferences ("*Is it the first time I visit this site or am I a regular user that knows quite well how are structured its pages and content and doesn't want / need too much verbosity ?*")

**Screen readers**
I recommend testing with at least one of the following combinations:

- Windows / Firefox / **[NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/)**
- OS X or iOS / VoiceOVer (already installed)

Even if open source NVDA is actively developed for modern web technologies, JAWS is still the most known and used scren reader. But this is a pricey commercial software which license does NOT allow you to use it for testing purposes, even if "it works for 40 minutes before needing to relaunch/reboot" so nope or be rich or get your company to buy it.

Never heard of Thunder, only of Window Eye(s) (except if it changed in 2013, it lags a lot for support of "modern" features like HTML5) and ORCA for GNU/Linux in a graphical environment (there are also screen readers for command line that would be fine for blind geeks, except modern browsers don't work in command line...)

**Accessible HTML code**

```
<table>
    <caption>Caption always useful</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">A</th>
            <th scope="col">B</th>
            <th scope="col">C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- if there's a tfoot element, it goes here -->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Relevant WCAG 2.0 Techniques** used in this simple example:

- [H39: Using caption elements to associate data table captions with data tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H39.html)
- [H51: Using table markup to present tabular information](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H51.html)
- [H63: Using the scope attribute to associate header cells and data cells in data tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H63.html)

Last one is for simple tables: a single row of header cells on top and/or a single column of header cells on left. Avoid using more complex tables, like having `colspan` or `rowspan` on header or data cells and/or many rows/columns of header cells. You can avoid this by splitting your table in simple ones for example, but that's not easy or allowed by your client/boss so if you've to code markup for these complex tables, first don't use `scope` attribute as it's no longer a header cell for the whole row/column (there are colspan/rowspan-ed cells somewhere) and then you should associate  the header cells with their data cells via `id` / `headers` mechanism. Again relevant WCAG 2.0 Technique is:

- [H43: Using id and headers attributes to associate data cells with header cells in data tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H63.html)

That's a complex task that needs perfect control over your HTML code, time+budget and well-trained content writers if they must associate themselves these cells! Sticking to simple tables is way better.

Comment: Depending on the data, it may be appropriate to have the initial column in each row marked as a row header - eg. <th scope="row">1</th> -- even if it's not visually marked up to look like a heading, the first