# How do I replace axis attribute in HTML5?

Tags: html, obsolete

I'm trying to have a script that will convert obsolete HTML in an old website to valid HTML5, but I'm struggling to find the replacement for the axis attribute.

The `axis` attribute on `td` and `th` elements was apparently meant to [set a category on table's (header) cells](https://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-axis-attribute.php).
According to https://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/obsolete.html, it should be replaced by the `scope` attribute.

However, [the `scope` attribute tells wether that the `th` element is a header for a cell or a column](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_th_scope.asp), but it does not put categories on `table` elements. Moreover, using the `scope` attribute on a `td` element is obsolete and it can only be used on a `th`.

So how to replace the `axis` attribute ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any client software which did anything useful with the `axis` attribute, so you could just replace it with nothing. This reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): What are you actually trying to achieve here? If you could use `axis`, what would you expect it to be used for and by what?

Comment: Edited, so maybe I could just delete it and it would be good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct replacement for `axis` in HTML 5, largely because browsers never did anything with it beyond exposing it on the DOM.

If there was a page which made practical use of it, then it would depend on JS in the page. The modern equivalent would be [a `data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) but that would require that the JS be updated as well as the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

For accessibility, I would continue to use the `scope` attribute on the `<th>` elements.  `<td>` elements shouldn't be used for headers in the first place.  Please see this other Stackoverflow question, "Making Data Tables Accessible for Screenreaders"  [Making Data Tables Accessible for Screenreaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150750/making-data-tables-accessible-for-screenreaders)
and this article on WebAim, "Creating Accessible Tables"  https://webaim.org/techniques/tables/data  for more information.  Best of luck.